# On 21 Sept 2016, Is pepper_49 the stable release right NOW?

Tags: google-nativeclient

Naclsdk list indicates pepper_49 as the stable release

```
C:\nacl_sdk>naclsdk.bat list
Bundles:
 I: installed
 *: update available

  I  sdk_tools (stable)
     vs_addin (dev)
     pepper_44 (post_stable)
  I  pepper_45 (post_stable)
     pepper_46 (post_stable)
     pepper_47 (post_stable)
  I  pepper_49 (stable)
     pepper_50 (beta)
     pepper_canary (canary)

All installed bundles are up-to-date.
```

But: in API reference page

Pepper C API Reference (Stable) saying: lists the C API for Pepper 48.

Pepper C API Reference (Beta) saying: lists the C API for Pepper 49.

This makes me think pepper_48 instead of pepper_49 being the stable release.

Also note, pepper_48 is NOT listed in naclsdk list.

Can anyone help clarify this for me please?

Answer (score 0):

Got a valid answer from Native-Client-Discuss Google Group as the following:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/native-client-discuss/6ormRPg8yE0

> Sadly the NaCl SDK is behind on publishing new releases.  We are
>   working  working on fixing that now: 
>   https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=648344.
>
> For now, please consider pepper_49 the latest stable release.

I am not sure why this question has been down-rated...